# How to configure url paths to GAE/java servlets

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I come from a python flask/django. I am trying to build an application using GAE-java. I just can't understand enough from the google appengine docs.

As far as I understand, creating .jsp files, itself maps to the jsp file name as the url path. But what if I want to write my own get method and post method ? What exactly is required for me to do ?

Right now my project structure looks like this.

[image]

And my web.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <filter>
      <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>com.signup.OfyHelper</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/signup.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.signup.SignupServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/signup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My signup.jsp as below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/static/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body class="login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
      <div class="login-logo">
        <b>SRH Fleet</b>
      </div>
      <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in</p>
        <form action="/signup" method="post">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input name="loginTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Login time (hh/mm)" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input name="logoutTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Logout Time" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input name="employeeClass" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee class" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <button align="center" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my ServletClass as below

```
package com.signup;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

public class SignupServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
        Date date = new Date();
        String employeeClass = request.getParameter("employeeClass");
        String location = request.getParameter("location");

        Employee newUser = new Employee(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber,
            date, date, employeeClass, location);

        ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(newUser).now();
        response.getWriter().println("Done");

    }

}
```

And I am getting this error

[image]

Here is my OfyHelper.java

```
package com.signup;

import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;


public class OfyHelper implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ObjectifyService.register(Employee.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Vehicle.class);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Using servlets is kind of like writing a python app without flask or django at all. You are going to do much better (faster, less frustrating, less bugs and more maintainable) using a web framework in Java. Spring is the defacto, but there are other options there that are closer to micro frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two servlets with the same name, so you should configure your two servlets with a different name.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>signupJsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/signup.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>signupServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.signup.SignupServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then you create two entries

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>signupJsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/signup.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>signupServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/signup</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That should do.

Since this is super basic i recommend your dig into how Java EE works.
Also this is pure Java EE configuration and has nothing to to with [app engine specifics](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) whatsoever.

**EDIT:**

I have not seen an OfyHelper implemented like that before. It's probably a racing condition between your query code and your entity registration.

Please read the [Objectify best practices](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BestPractices) regarding this topic. I do my entity registration like this:

```
public class OfyService {
    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Employee.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Vehicle.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

and then do queries like

```
OfyService.ofy()....
```

which works very reliable and is also what Jeff aka [stickfigure](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635982) recommends, well last i heard at least.

Make sure you import the correct entity classes in your OfyService class. If you have multiple Employee classes in different packages and import the wrong one the error you mentioned can happen as well.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I will definitely read about javaEE.

I had tried all possible ways and documentations, I didn't get what information you gave. Thank you. 

But just one more thing, I am getting another error, although I understand what the error is, I can't quite figure out why. 

After posting to /signup, I am creating an entry of Employee Class in the datastore. but I get this error "No class 'com.signup.Employee' was registered". But I believe I have registered in OfyHelper,java. 

I will update OfyHelper.java in the question. 

Once again, thank you so much !

Comment: Thank you so much, I worked all night and figured out that Objectify wants the Model Class's Constructor to be empty. I was taking arguments which was causing the error. 

Thank you !!!